# android:theme parameter inside manifest ignored

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles, android-studio-3.1

I have AppTheme style in my styles.xml file. In manifest file i choose it like application theme.
I want to login activity unique style and I created login style, and set it in manifest. But it is not working, LoginActivity still takes AppTheme.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".application.TrainerApp"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.login.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LoginTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

**In style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LoginTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

[image: changing theme in design editor helped!!]

Comment: in your login theme use different colors

Comment: I tried that. Nothing changes

Comment: Try this removing the theme at an app level and specify a theme for every activity you add to your application.

Comment: can you show how did you applied

Comment: see what @MoinKhan did below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :-

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LoginTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0ff</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#f0f</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Instead of :-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LoginTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, please update your answer to which you solved ...

Comment: @AxborAxrorov this updated ans but it is matching as your question

Comment: look at question. and update your answer to right answer, to help others too

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from your application tag and apply theme for each activity separately. For more detail, please see my link: http://androidkeeda.com/android-working-on-material-theme